# How to set max limit integer

Tags: javascript, regex

I have price field and i have code to validate price field.

```
$("#price").inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d*[.,]?\d{0,2}$/.test(value);
});
```

from above code after "." only 2 digit can enter in input field. but i need to validate max integer to 4. ie. 2555.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to allow for prices which are strictly less than 10,000 you may use `^-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{2})?$`.  Your updated code:

```
$("#price").inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{2})?$/.test(value);
});
```